# How does doxygen generate Nodes.xml?

Tags: doxygen

When I upgraded from Doxygen 1.7.6.1 with custom options to 1.8.8 with the default Doxyfile options, the Nodes.xml file was not generated.  Which option is needed to generate Nodes.xml?

Answer (score 2):

GENERATE_DOCSET = YES

This option creates the following files:
Nodes.xml, Tokens.xml, makefile, and plist.info
Running makefile will copy your API's documentation to a pre-determined location where Xcode, upon starting, can find and load for use.